# How to upgrade and set default kernel on CentOS Stream

Tags: centos, vmware

This is a virtual machine (vmware) on vCenter

### Current Kernel `3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64`

```bash
[root@stage ~]# uname -a
Linux stage.dsr.FILTERED.net 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 16:44:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
[root@stage ~]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: stage.dsr.FILTERED.net
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 4121FILTERED1663
           Boot ID: b264FILTEREDa2dc
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: CentOS Stream 8
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:8
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

### Installed latest kernel

```bash
sudo dnf --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml kernel-ml-devel kernel-ml-headers
```

```bash
[root@stage ~]# sudo dnf --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml kernel-ml-devel kernel-ml-headers
Last metadata expiration check: 0:36:34 ago on Tue 21 Jun 2022 23:59:55 BST.
Package kernel-ml-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-ml-devel-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-ml-headers-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

### Checking available images in `/boot`

```bash
[root@stage boot]# ls -al
total 91212
dr-xr-xr-x.  6 root root      272 Jun 22 00:06 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root root      224 Jun 22 00:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root       17 Aug 30  2018 efi
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        6 Jun 22 00:07 grub
drwx------.  5 root root      156 Jun 21 23:48 grub2
-rw-------.  1 root root 55388571 Aug 30  2018 initramfs-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663.img
-rw-------.  1 root root 12508372 Jun  7 18:44 initramfs-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64kdump.img
-rw-------.  1 root root 19272908 Jun 22 00:06 initramfs-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.img
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root       21 Jun 21 23:48 loader
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  6224704 Aug 30  2018 vmlinuz-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663
```

### List default kernel

```bash
[root@stage boot]# grubby --default-kernel
/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663
```

### List out available

```bash
[root@stage boot]# ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 6224704 Aug 30  2018 /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663
```

There is only one entry!

### Listing out RPM kernel packages

```bash
[root@stage boot]# rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-ml-devel-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
kernel-ml-headers-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
kernel-ml-modules-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
kernel-ml-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
kernel-ml-core-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
```

## How do I install and set `5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64` to be the new default kernel?

Any pointers are most welcome

## UPDATE 20220622

```bash
[root@stage ~]# dracut --force
dracut: Cannot find module directory /lib/modules/3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64/
dracut: and --no-kernel was not specified
```

also tried

```bash
dracut --kver 5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 --force
dracut --regenerate-all --force
```

but I still only have one same `vmlinuz-` in the the `/boot` folder

```bash
[root@stage boot]# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root       17 Aug 30  2018 efi
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        6 Jun 22 00:07 grub
drwx------.  5 root root      156 Jun 22 16:44 grub2
-rw-------.  1 root root 55388571 Aug 30  2018 initramfs-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663.img
-rw-------.  1 root root 12508372 Jun  7 18:44 initramfs-3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64kdump.img
-rw-------.  1 root root 19457348 Jun 22 17:32 initramfs-5.18.5-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.img
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root       21 Jun 21 23:48 loader
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  6224704 Aug 30  2018 vmlinuz-0-rescue-4121a368f8744621872224e7593f1663
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems kernel files are missing.

Try reinstall kernel by

```
dnf remove kernel-ml
dnf --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
```

kernel 5.x should bas been set by default.

verify it by

```
grubby --default-kernel
```

if not, set it manually

```
grubby --set-default /boot/vmlinuz-5.xxx.el8.elrepo.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

try `dracut --force` and `grub2-mkconfig`

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `dracut --force` gives me a `dracut: Cannot find module directory /lib/modules/3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64/` I have tried specifying a kernel to no avail. BTW Can you vote up the question please? thank you

Comment: although `dracut` looks like a good pointer, I still haven't resolve my issue. I will update my question accordingly.